# How to split string with inconsistent order format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to split the strings in the 'Scorer' column so that the scorer name is retained but not the score type (i.e. to remove the text within the brackets and the brackets to just leave the scorer name in that field).

```
Scorer
Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)
Ellis J.(Try)
Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)
Trueman J.(Try)
(Conversion Goal)Brough D.
(Try)McGillvary J.
(Try)McGillvary J.
(Penalty Goal)Brough D.
Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)
```

[image]

It should look like the below.

```
Scorer
Ellis J.
Ellis J.
Ellis J.
Trueman J.
Brough D.
McGillvary J.
McGillvary J.
Brough D.
Ellis J.
```

Comment: Welcomde to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution would be to fix the database structure by adding another column to the table for the score type. In fact, you should probably have a table for score types and add a foreign key to it from this table.

Assuming you can't change the database structure, this is better done at the presentation layer. Any programming language should enable you do do it quite easily. String manipulation is not SQL's strong suit.

That being said, it can certainly be done using pure T-SQL - with a simple common table expression to get the brackets indexes using `charindex`, and a case expression with `stuff` in the select statement.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Scorer nvarchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @T (Scorer) VALUES
('Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)'),
('Ellis J.(Try)'),
('Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)'),
('Trueman J.(Try)'),
('(Conversion Goal)Brough D.'),
('(Try)McGillvary J.'),
('(Try)McGillvary J.'),
('(Penalty Goal)Brough D.'),
('Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)'),
-- Note: I've added some edge cases to the sample data:
('a row with (brackets) in the middle'),
('Just an open bracket (forgot to close '),
('Just a close bracket forgot to open)'),
('no brackets at all'),
('brackets ) in reversed order (');
```

Then, the CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Scorer, 
            CHARINDEX('(', Scorer) As OpenBrackets,
            CHARINDEX(')', Scorer) As CloseBrackets
    FROM @T
)
```

The select statement:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN OpenBrackets > 0 AND CloseBrackets > OpenBrackets
        THEN
           STUFF(Scorer, OpenBrackets, CloseBrackets - OpenBrackets + 1, '') 
        ELSE
            Scorer
        END As Scorer
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
Scorer
Ellis J.
Ellis J.
Ellis J.
Trueman J.
Brough D.
McGillvary J.
McGillvary J.
Brough D.
Ellis J.
a row with  in the middle
Just an open bracket (forgot to close 
Just a close bracket forgot to open)
no brackets at all
brackets ) in reversed order (
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query works for you

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Scorer, SUBSTRING(Scorer, CHARINDEX('(', Scorer), CHARINDEX(')', Scorer) - CHARINDEX('(', Scorer) + 1), '')))
FROM <TABLENAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'Ellis J.(Conversion Goal)' union all
 select '(Conversion Goal)Brough D.' union all   
 select '  (Try)McGillvary J.'   
)
select (case when charindex('(', ltrim(str)) = 1 then
              substring(str,charindex(')', str)+1,len(str))
             else           
               left(str, charindex('(', str) - 1)          
             end) as "Scorers"        
  from t

    Scorers
  --------------
   Ellis J.
   Brough D.
   McGillvary J.
```

by contribution of `substring`, `charindex` and `left` functions together. `ltrim` is used against probabilty of spaces left before `(` character at the beginning of the string.

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/NHG45159)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

These two pieces of information (the name and action) should not be in the same column. You should create a separate column for name and for action. And if the position of the action (before or after the name) is important, you might even need an additional column for that.

When you have migrated your data after that - in other words when you have cleaned up - you could still create a view or a computed column to output the `scorer` the way you do now, for example

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD scorer AS athlete_name + ' (' + action + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT Scorer
,CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%(%)%',Scorer) > 1 
THEN LEFT(Scorer, PATINDEX('%(%)%',Scorer)-1)
ELSE RIGHT (Scorer, LEN(Scorer) - CHARINDEX(')',Scorer,1) )
END AS ColumnName
FROM ScoreTable
```

this should work assuming you only expect 1 instance if the pattern per row, but will work whether the "()" data is at the front or the back of the values

Comment: the solution assumes the scorer's name will be entirely to the left or right of the "(%)" pattern. you may need to tweak the code in the expression slightly to accommodate your case